# Why is my connector not receiving the host's message?

Tags: java, sockets

#### Summary

I'm making a simple peer-to-peer chess game in Java. The host successfully connects, but the connector doesn't get its message. I am using a `PrintWriter` and `BufferedReader` to send and receive messages. I suspect the `PrintWriter` is misbehaving, but I am not sure.

#### Prior research

I searched for 'Client not receiving server's message' but the problem everyone was having was not using `println` with their `PrintWriter`. I do use `println`, so none of them applied to me. I also moved the input and output fields out of the method and into the class, which one answer said to do, but it did not fix the problem.

## Some code

#### Listening code

```java
try (ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(this.port)) {
    // We need to connect with another computer
    if (this.other == null || this.other.isClosed()) {
        System.out.println("Looking for connection on port " + serverSocket.getLocalPort());
        this.in = null;
        this.out = null;
        // Listen for connectors
        this.other = serverSocket.accept();
        // Someone tried to connect, handle connection
        System.out.println("Player connected");
        this.in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(this.other.getInputStream()));
        this.out = new PrintWriter(this.other.getOutputStream(), true);
        // Autoflush is enabled!                                 ^^^^
        // This does not get to the client
        this.sendMessage("connectHost");
    }
    // We are currently connected to another computer, no need to look for more
    else {
        String input = this.in.readLine();
        System.out.println("Received '" + input + "'");
        
        if (input != null) {
            // Handle input
        }
    }
} catch (IOException ioe) {
    ioe.printStackTrace();
}
```

#### Sending code

```java
if (this.out != null) {
    // See, it is println, so I don't need to call out.flush()...
    this.out.println(message);
    System.out.println("Sent '" + message + "'");
}
```

#### Connection command code

```java
try {
    // The host picks up on this
    this.other = new Socket(ip, port);
    this.in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(this.other.getInputStream()));
    this.out = new PrintWriter(this.other.getOutputStream(), true);
    // Works
    this.sendMessage("test");
} catch (IOException ioe) {
    ioe.printStackTrace();
}
```

#### Problem

It should print out `Received 'connectHost'` on the connector, but that does not happen. Instead, it blocks, from the `in.readLine()` being called without `in` having received data. If I insert an `in.ready()` check, it will always return `false`.

#### Connector console

```
Looking for connection on port 57479
connect localhost 57478 // Command to connect to host
Sent 'test' // Successfully goes to the host
// Now it blocks. This is intended, but it should be saying "Received 'connectHost'" beforehand.
```

#### Host console

```
Looking for connection on port 57478
Player connected
Sent 'connectHost'
Received 'test' // Host gets it
// This also blocks, waiting for more messages, but that is intended.
```

Update:
I just tried sending a message directly after connection (see updated code) and the host gets it. The connector still does not get the one from the host.

Comment: Where is th e code that prints what you have labelled as 'connector console'?

Comment: If you are sending (and receiving) from both server and client then you will need seperate threads for each listening socket

Comment: The "connect code" doesn't set this.in or this.out, is that intentional?

Comment: @Scary Wombat There are two instances of the same code running.

Comment: @immibis Seeing your comment, I tried it, but no difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### It was obvious...

The `serverSocket.accept()` was blocking, preventing the connector from reading input. So the `in.readLine()` was not the problem. I made it so the user must tell the program to listen for connections. Now it works.

### New code

#### Listening code

```java
try (ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(this.port)) {
    if (this.listening && (this.other == null || this.other.isClosed())) {
        System.out.println("Looking for connection on port " + serverSocket.getLocalPort());
        this.in = null;
        this.out = null;
        this.other = serverSocket.accept();
        this.in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(this.other.getInputStream()));
        this.out = new PrintWriter(this.other.getOutputStream(), true);
    } else if (this.in != null) {System.out.println("Looking for input");
        String input = this.in.readLine();
        System.out.println("Received '" + input + "'");

        if (input != null) {
            // Process input
        }
    }
} catch (IOException ioe) {
    ioe.printStackTrace();
}
```

Sending code was unchanged.

#### Connection code

```java
if (input.contains("connect")) {
    String[] args = input.replaceAll("connect ", "").split(" ");
    String ip = args[0];
    int port = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);

    try {
        this.other = new Socket(ip, port);
        this.in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(this.other.getInputStream()));
        this.out = new PrintWriter(this.other.getOutputStream(), true);
        this.sendMessage("connect");
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    }
} else if (input.contains("listen")) {
    this.listening = true;
}
```